# Ubuntu sound disappeared

Tags: sound, ubuntu-mate, lspci

I have Ubuntu Mate (15.10) installed on my Dell laptop. Everything was working until I ran a software upgrader. After installing updates and rebooting sound disappeared.

Here are the outputs of `aplay -l` and `sudo lspci -v`: http://pastebin.com/EptH0unq

What might be the reason and how to fix the problem?

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu Mate (16.04 this time), got my sound fixed, wifi broken again see this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/753545/ubuntu-wi-fi-stopped-working-after-upgrade-to-16-04 (granted, broadcom is a pita for Linux). So there will be no follow up story

Answer (score 1):

Fellow Linux lovers, remember, that Linux viruses deal way less damage to ordinary users than regular updates. This is not a bug, but a feature. Community is small, so there is not as many attackers and/or testers  Go for Windows, if you want it the other way around.

So, don't try to install updates right away. Backup the system first using Clonezilla or a similar tool. Keep old backups just in case.